# Getting AWS AppSync to work with CloudFront and a custom domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-appsync

I've got an AppSync server, which uses an API_KEY generated by AppSync. Previously I had a React application in S3, and just the raw AppSync API url. That worked absolutely fine. Since putting them both behind a domain name in Route53, both backed by a separate Cloudfront distribution, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorType" : "UnauthorizedException",
    "message" : "You are not authorized to make this call."
  } ]
}
```

I think the x-api-key header is possibly being stripped out between Cloudfront and the AppSync origin. But I can't see where to allow custom headers in Cloudfront. Do I also need to enable IAM roles between Cloudfront and AppSync?

UPDATE:
I found the custom-headers section, added those, they appear in the request headers now but still the same error.

Comment: Did you take a look at this blog? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-a-custom-domain-with-aws-appsync-amazon-cloudfront-and-amazon-route-53/